# Excel apply functions on FILTER. ie COUNTIF(FILTER(RANGE,FilterCondition),IfCondition)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel doesn't seem to let you use function such as RANK/COUNTIF on a FILTER(...) formula without first having the output of the filter somewhere in the spreadsheet. Ie, functions take range as argument but not arrays.

Let's assume in Column A, I have number 1 to 10 on the ten first rows

and in column B a filter on even numbers, `=FILTER(A1:A10,MOD(A1:A10,2)=0)`

If I want to count the number of rows of array returned by the filter function, I can use `=COUNT(B1#)`

If I want to count only the values above 5 using `COUNTIF`, this will also work `=COUNTIF(B1#, ">5")`

Now, I would like to get rid of the intermediary B Column.

For the `COUNT` function, it works. `=COUNT(FILTER(A1:A10,MOD(A1:A10,2)=0))` returns 5.

For the `COUNTIF` function, it doesn't work anymore. I assume this because it takes a range as a parameter and not an array.

Excel warns in a popup: "There's a problem with this formula".

Is there a workaround this without using a temporary column to store the array? It seems I can only use functions that takes an array as parameter on top of the filter function.

EDIT:
I have used `COUNTIF` to build a simple example but I am more interested in other functions such has `RANK`.
COUNTIF was not the best example because you can obviously move the IF conditions in the FILTER conditions. Thank you @JvdV

Comment: You should use a multiplication inside the `FILTER()` it's 2nd paramter: `=COUNT(FILTER(A1:A10,(MOD(A1:A10,2)=0)*(A1:A10>5)))` as indeed, it's not possible inside `COUNTIFS()`. If you don't want to use `FILTER()` a simple `SUM()` will do >> `=SUM((MOD(A1:A10,2)=0)*(A1:A10>5))`

Comment: Ok good point, but I also wanted to use other functions, in particular RANK. I'll amend the question accordingly. Thank you

Comment: `=FILTER(A1:A10,RANK(A1:A10,A1:A10)<=5)` works fine

Comment: If I want to use countif, I want the function to return just the number 3, not a range. If I want to use Rank, for instance of number 6, function should return 3. My problem is to apply the functions on a filtered range, and for that excel sem to force write it down first somewhere on the spreadsheet.